# Transparent fill for Photoshop vector shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a round rectangle and I want it to only be 20% filled in, but somehow changing the fill affects how my outside stroke looks. Is there a way to keep the stroke nice while making the fill nearly transparent?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using a layer style? With a style, the vector image fill and transparency can be adjusted without affecting the stroke.

Stroke layer style:

[image]

Stroke with % fill changed:

[image]